# c# list.Add complication

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have class MyClass() in which I am calling method from another SecondClass() it is done is foreach loop. In this method I have a list to which I am putting some data. But everytime this method is called my list is filled from the begining. I lose all previously inserted data. How can I fix this problem?

```
foreach(string items in description)
{
    SecondClass method = new SecondClass();
    method.DoThis(items);
}
```

MyClass() with this method looks something like this

```
public void DoThis(string items)
{
    List<MyClass> list2 = new List<MyClass>();
    if(//somethis)
    {
         /// some more code
         list2.Add(sk);
    }
}
```

I edited the code, I had some mistakes. Sorry

Comment: You have something wrong with logic or data storage

Comment: What do you want to achieve? By words, what you have and what you need

Comment: I don't understand, why do always create new `SecondClass`?

Comment: need to clarify your question: shouldn't `DoThis` be part of `SecondClass` rather than `MyClass`?

Comment: @FSou1 Ok, you are right, I can move it outside the loop.

Comment: If you can move it outside the loop, you can pass your `description` collection directly in `DoThis` as parameter, or into `constructor` when you will create `SecondClass(description)`

Comment: @FSou1 This is exactly what I needed. Now it is saving all data inside my list. Thank you.

Comment: Great, hope we helped ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're initializing `list2` inside `DoThis`'s scope.
You have to declare it as a member of `MyClass`, like the following:

```
class MyClass
{
      //if MyClass is sealed or static, then change protected to private.
      //if you need to access it from outside MyClass, change it to public.
      protected List<SrodkowaKolumna> list2 = new List<SrodkowaKolumna>();

      public void DoThis(string items)
      {
           if(//somethis)
           {
                 /// some more code
                 list2.Add(sk);
           }
      }
 }
```

Comment: Thing that FSoul told me helped, but I also had to put my list outside my method. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

It should store your list as field in class. When you were initializing list2 in DoThis, every single call was making new empty list2.

```
public class MyClass
{
    List<SrodkowaKolumna> list2;
    public MyClass()
    {
         list2 = new List<SrodkowaKolumna>();
    }
    //.... other code

    public void DoThis(string items)
    {  
       for(//somethis)
       {
         /// some more code
                list2.Add(sk);
       }
     }
}
```